# Popup for an active edit beneath the post contains the button that doesn’t fit into popup

Tags: bug, design, suggested-edits, responsive-design, popups

When the post has an active suggested edit tapping on the link `edit (1)` leads to the opening a popup. That popup doesn't fit into screen width in responsive mode on phone's screen:

> [image]

Animation was taken on ruSO so there's maybe localization issue as well due to the length of translated strings.

Possible solution is to use different rows for the text and for the buttons block.

Comment: Reproduced on Stack Overflow, so it's not just for localized sites. Also, the overall design is terrible in the popup, buttons should be of same height.